# Cart Become empty in codeigniter when I logged in through Google api

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

Every thing is ok in my site. adding products in cart is ok. And when I login through facebook, twitter and even with registered account then my cart records show perfectly . But unfortunately when I login with google api then its login successfully but my cart become empty.

```
 //////  here is my code when google come at my page after getting data./////

   $this->user_model->insert('users',
                              array('email'=>$users_info['email'], 
                                    'fname'=>$users_info['given_name'],
                                    'lname'=>$users_info['family_name'],
                                     'pic'=>$users_info['picture']
                             ));

   $id = $this->user_model->get_last_insert_id(); 

 ////////Setting session values//////////////////////////

  $sess_array = array(
            'id' =>$id,
            'email' => $users_info['email'],
            'is_logged_in' =>TRUE
                 );
  $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
  redirect(base_url('/'));
  exit();
```

Here is my shopping cart url
   https://www.dealsmug.com/

Comment: may be your `cart session` is getting destroyed when you login with `google api`.. you need to work on this line `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);`

Comment: thanks for respond but cart session only destroy at the time of order completed. here is not any coding for this. please can u mention that what I am to do in mentioned line by u.

Comment: if your cart session in not getting destroyed than your cart doesnt become empty.. And I am not sure but this function is setting new session data and destroying the last session.. you need to check the function.. `set_userdata()`...

Comment: try putting `session_set_cookie_params('3600');` in the top of the page before you put `session_start()`.....

Comment: but cookie session is false in my config file there is enable database session

Comment: ohh ok than are you loading `session library` in codeigniter before setting up the variable.. `$this->load->library('session');`...

Comment: And before set user session cart become emtpy
as show
array(0) {
}

Comment: This library is loaded automatically because this is include in aoutoload.php fine

Comment: Now I include this $this->load->library('session'); in login file but same situation .

Comment: than something is wrong with your `config` file.. try applying some different config patterns..

Comment: But there is another thing. If I login from cart page. and redirect after login at cart page then my cart have values but my user session are not setting. :)

Comment: But If I redirect at base  url then cart become empty and user session are ok :)

Comment: u can check at site if some time  with thanks

Comment: when you are redirecting to `google api link` than your session value is getting destroyed... please try changing your config parameters..

Comment: please tell me what I am to do in config file to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=tM1YU-L9G4OrrAfJmYBg#q=codeigniter+session+problem